# How to filter objects with date > today or empty date from a Model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I need to select all model objects with date field greater than today date OR date field empty.

I have following code:

```
@login_required
def event_new(request, person_uuid=None):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    # valid_until may be empty
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(company=request.user.company,
                                     valid_until__gte=today)
```

I need to select all Profile objects with valid_until field empty or (if set) greater than today.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

```
from django.db.models import Q

@login_required
def event_new(request, person_uuid=None):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    #valid_until may be empty
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(company=request.user.company).filter(Q(valid_until__gte=today)|Q(valid_until=None))
```