# DJANGO Queryset with datetime: Need to get all future dated entries

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset, backend

How would I get all the entries in the model Appointment with a future date using datetime?
The attribute in question is date.

```
Appointment.object.filter(date = ???? )
```

Comment: try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#gte

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568044/get-objects-with-date-greater-than-today-or-empty-date

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#gte) (*greater than or equal to*) lookup:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> today = datetime.today()
>>> Appointment.object.filter(date__gte=today)
```